# Processing a mainframe file using cobrix in databricks - Pyspark python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, cobol, mainframe

Does anyone know on how to integrate cobrix in azure databricks - pyspark for processing a mainframe file , having comp-3 columns(Python 3 )

Please find the below link for detailed issue.
https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix/issues/236#issue-550885564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make third-party or locally-built code available to notebooks and jobs running on your clusters, you can install a library. Libraries can be written in Python, Java, Scala, and R. You can upload Java, Scala, and Python libraries and point to external packages in PyPI, Maven, and CRAN repositories.

**Steps to install third party libraries:**

**Step1:** Create Databricks Cluster.

**Step2:** Select the cluster created.

**Step3:** Select Libraries => Install New => Select Library Source = "Maven" => Coordinates => Search Packages => Select Maven Central => Search for the package required. Example: (spark-cobol, cobol-parser, scodec) => Select the version required => Install

[image]

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks - libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries)" and "[Cobrix: A Mainframe Data Source for Spark SQL and Streaming](https://databricks.com/session/cobrix-a-mainframe-data-source-for-spark-sql-and-streaming)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.